Python multiprocessing is slow on slurm
I'm using Python multiprocessing and then submitting the job with sbatch. The .sh code is as follows:
#!/bin/bash
##----------------------- Start job description ----------------------- 
#SBATCH --partition=standard
#SBATCH --job-name=multi_Leaspy
#SBATCH --nodes=1
#SBATCH --ntasks=40
#SBATCH --mem-per-cpu=4096
#SBATCH --time=160:00:00
#SBATCH --mail-type=ALL
#SBATCH --output=out-%j.log
#SBATCH --error=err-%j.log
##------------------------ End job description ------------------------ 

This is the snippet where i parallelize the code:
num_workers = ntasks = int(os.environ.get('SLURM_NTASKS', 1))
if __name__ == "__main__":
        with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers = num_workers - 1) as executor:       
            arg_list = [(i, row, df_test, id_test, btstrp, classes, classes_auc, 
                      results_table, MAE_table, features_set, vector_range) for i, row in feat_sub.iterrows()]
            for result, MAE_row in executor.map(multiLeaspyIter, arg_list):
                if result is not None and MAE_row is not None:
                    results_table = results_table.append(result, ignore_index=True)
                    MAE_table = MAE_table.append(MAE_row, ignore_index = True)

Then, i ssh and htop to see the resource utilization and there are more executing processes than requested. Furthermore, many waiting processes appear, slowing down everything.
htop results:
Tasks = 1627, 501 thr, 40 running
Load average = 201.3, 180.94, 117.36
Each node has 40 cpus, hyper-threading enabled.
Previously, i was using ProcessPoolExecutor, same code, and it was far slower.
I'm not sure whether multiprocessing is appropiate for a slurm environment or i'm missing something.
Previously, i was using ProcessPoolExecutor, same code, and it was slower.
When i configure the .sh so --ntasks = 1 and the .py so max_workers = 1, the code runs faster. If --ntasks = 5 and max_workers = 5, it goes slower and creates aditional waiting processes.
Apart from that, i noticed with just 1 process, many threads are created.
I've tried the same code on Windows and it goes faster.

try allocate more processes/cores, may be --cpus-per-task=1 or another amount

It seems that you are using sbatch to create 40 tasks and then each of those creates another 40. Choose one mechanism or the other.

Tangentially, the code you put inside if __name__ == "__main__": should be absolutely trivial (or else you should omit this condition). The condition is only useful when you import this code; if all the useful functionality is excluded when you import, you will never want to do that anyway. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/69778466/874188

You should check the binding of processes to cores. AFAIK tools like Slurm and MPI tends to forces the binding (often to improve performance of HPC codes) unless the default binding does not fit your needs. Also check that the program itself is not executed many times (like with an MPI code).

Do as I told just to experiment. Spawning tasks on compute node might work a bit different from login. Also confirm how you inovoke the task. Is there anything in your .sh files beside comments?
